# NSXMLDocument error with opening file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsurl, nsxmldocument

I am trying to read a file into NSXMLDocument. Here my code:

```
NSString *urlString = [@"~/Library/Preferences/Quark/QuarkXPress 8/OutputStyles.xml" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSError *error = nil;

NSXMLDocument *doc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", error);
NSLog(@"%@", doc);
```

but, in console I get:

```
2011-04-19 07:41:09.914 XMLTest[1409:a0f] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1014 UserInfo=0x1001289d0 "zero byte resource"
2011-04-19 07:41:09.915 XMLTest[1409:a0f] (null)
```

Any suggestion about what could be wrong? I have the file there..I checked it like a 100 times...
Thanks.

EDIT:
When I try to read this in a NSString using [stringwithcontentofurl encoding error] method i get this error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=262 UserInfo=0x1006281c0 "The
>   file couldn’t be opened because the
>   specified URL type isn’t supported."
>   Underlying Error=(Error
>   Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002
>   UserInfo=0x1006280d0 "unsupported URL"
>   Underlying Error=(Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork
>   Code=-1002 UserInfo=0x100627d50
>   "unsupported URL"))

Comment: Try @"~/Library/Preferences/Quark/QuarkXPress\ 8/OutputStyles.xml" please.

Comment: Nop doesn't work. And I also get a warning of unknown escape sequence. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: and @"~/Library/Preferences/Quark/QuarkXPress 8/OutputStyles.xml", there was a // in that url string, now without quoting the space.

Comment: sorry, that // was a mistake, i removed it in the original mesag.e

Comment: Ah! Can you prepend file:// after calling stringByExpandingTildeInPath?

Comment: Nice, then it should be the answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prepend `file://` after calling stringByExpandingTildeInPath :)

Answer (score 0):

Prepend file: not file://
for example

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:([NSString stringWithFormat:@"file:/Users/name/Desktop/%@",fileName])];
```